# Compiling meshlab on Centos EL7

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, ld, meshlab, qt5.9

I'm have trouble compiling meshlab-2016.12 on Centos.EL7.
I got some of the way.
Updated QT to Qt-5.9.1 as latest on Centos is Qt version 5.6.1 - which I had previously installed

```
sudo yum install qt5-qtbase
sudo yum install qt5-qtx11extras
sudo yum install qt5-qtbase-devel
```

However at least Qt5.7 is needed for meshlab

Then set these env. variables

```
setenv QTDIR /usr/local/Qt-5.9.1
setenv QTINC /usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/include
setenv QTLIB /usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/lib 
setenv PATH /usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/bin:$PATH
setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/bin:$PATH
```

Then followed instructions on a test machine, installing into /opt/TESTING

1. Installed vcglib into /opt/TESTING
2. downloaded meshlab-2016.12 into /opt/TESTING and unpacked it there
3. Ran the following

   qmake -project

(This picks up the correct version of QT)

```
qmake src/external/external.pro
```

(To make the external libraries - including jhead-2.95

```
gmake
gmake install
```

(To make the external libraries - including jhead-2.95 )

```
qmake src/meshlab_mini.pro
```

(To build meshlab with a minimal set of plugins )

This is where it fails, as below;

```
../../vcglib/vcg/complex/algorithms/clean.h:1789:0: 
warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]

pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 10)

g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../distrib -Wl,-rpath,
/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/lib -o ../distrib/meshlab main.o mainwindow_Init.o 
mainwindow_RunTime.o glarea.o multiViewer_Container.o plugindialog.o 
customDialog.o filterScriptDialog.o saveSnapshotDialog.o layerDialog.o 
savemaskexporter.o changetexturename.o stdpardialog.o ml_std_par_dialog.o 
xmlstdpardialog.o additionalgui.o xmlgeneratorgui.o ml_render_gui.o 
ml_rendering_actions.o ml_default_decorators.o ml_selection_buffers.o
trackball.o trackmode.o coordinateframe.o glarea_setting.o filterthread.o
qrc_meshlab.o moc_interfaces.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_glarea.o
moc_multiViewer_Container.o moc_plugindialog.o moc_customDialog.o 
moc_filterScriptDialog.o moc_saveSnapshotDialog.o moc_savemaskexporter.o 
moc_changetexturename.o moc_layerDialog.o moc_stdpardialog.o 
moc_ml_std_par_dialog.o moc_xmlstdpardialog.o moc_additionalgui.o 
moc_xmlgeneratorgui.o moc_ml_render_gui.o moc_ml_rendering_actions.o 
moc_filterthread.o   -L../external/lib/linux-g++ -ljhead -L../distrib 
-lcommon -lGLU -L/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/lib -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui 
-lQt5Xml -lQt5XmlPatterns -lQt5Network -lQt5Script -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/bin/ld: cannot find -ljhead
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [../distrib/meshlab] Error 1    
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/TESTING/meshlab-2016.12/meshlab'    
gmake: *** [sub-meshlab-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

So it's saying ld can't find ljhead.  Other parts of the compile do seem to be finding it though eg

```
-I../src/external/glew-1.7.0/include -I../src/external/jhead-2.95
```

Looking at ld

```
/bin/ld -V
GNU ld version 2.25.1-22.base.el7 
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
```

and 
/

```
usr/bin/ld -V
GNU ld version 2.25.1-22.base.el7 
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
```

Any advice would be useful at this point.  Hopefully I've just missed something out

Updated:
Tried workaround from William Brown below, which gave some progress.  Failed at later point

```
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/src/meshlab/meshlabplugins/filter_layer'
cd meshlabplugins/filter_measure/ && ( test -e Makefile || /opt/bin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake 
/opt/src/meshlab/src/meshlabplugins/filter_measure/filter_measure.pro -o Makefile ) && gmake -f Makefile 
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/opt/src/meshlab/meshlabplugins/filter_measure'
gmake[1]: *** No rule to make target `filter_measure.xml', needed by `../../distrib/plugins/libfilter_measure.so'.  Stop.
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/src/meshlab/meshlabplugins/filter_measure'
gmake: *** [sub-meshlabplugins-filter_measure-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get past that problem on Centos 7 (7.3.1611).

There seem to be 2 issues, and I don't claim that this is the right fix, just a work-around.

After unpacking the tar file I `cd` to the top level (I have unpacked to `/local/meshlab`).  I then create a link:

```
# ln -s ./src/external eternal
```

The reason being that the -L in the statement that fails seems to be pointed to an external folder at that top level, not in `./src`.

Having done that I can build external.pro without any problem, and the output .a files all go into `/local/meshlab/lib/linux-g++`.   Without the link they were deep down in a temporary build folder.

However the -L doesn't look there, it looks in `/local/meshlab/src/external/lib/linux-g++/`, where there are some pre-shipped .a files already.  So I copy the .a files to there:

```
# cp /local/meshlab/lib/linux-g++/*.a /local/meshlab/src/external/lib/linux-g++/
```

Now when I use:

```
# qmake src/meshlab_mini.pro
# gmake
```

It works and builds a runnable meshlab binary in `/local/meshlab/distrib`.

Comment: Thanks William.  That got rid of the errors I reported.  Unfortunately it generated another one (I'm trying to build the meshlab_full.pro

    `gmake[1]: *** No rule to make target `filter_measure.xml', needed by `../../distrib/plugins/libfilter_measure.so'.  Stop.`

Progress though!!